# Image not inserting to database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I'm attempting to add some image upload functionality to a web app I'm writing and I've run into a bit of an issue. For some reason, anytime I attempt to execute the image save function the image fails to insert.

Here's my function:

```
Public Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If fileupload1.HasFile Then

        Dim pimage(fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength - 1) As Byte
        pimage = fileupload1.FileBytes
        Dim pid As String = partnum.Text.ToString
        Dim sConnection As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=inteva; UID=root; PASSWORD=root; OPTION=3"
        Dim connectme As New OdbcConnection(sConnection)
        Dim sInsertInto As String = "INSERT INTO images(id_num, serial, image1) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), @pserial, @ppimage)"
        Dim com As New OdbcCommand(sInsertInto, connectme)

        com.Parameters.Add("@pserial", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pid
        com.Parameters.Add("@ppimage", OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = pimage


        connectme.Open()
        Dim result As Integer = com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connectme.Close()


        If result > 0 Then
            lblimageup.Text = "Image saved."
        End If

    Else
        lblimageup.Text = "Please select an image file"


    End If

End Sub
```

Any ideas on why the image isn't inserting?

Comment: Did you get any errors? Did you try to execute your `INSERT`-statement with sample-parameters on the SQL-server itself? More info needed on this.

Comment: Also, what's your DB schema?

Comment: The only error is the fact that the image column is non-null and the image won't insert. For testing purposes I allowed the column to accept nulls and checked the database, the image simply does not save to the database.

The schema is utf8-default